# How do I add a reference to a server control in my current website to the web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, custom-server-controls

I have extended a server control (not a user control) and put the code in my app_code folder. 
I would like to add a tag prefix to the web config, but

```
<add tagPrefix="cc1" namespace="mynamespace" />
```

and

```
<add tagPrefix="cc1" namespace="mynamespace" assembly="currentwebsitename" />
```

don't work.
I get this error:
Error   147 Unknown server tag 'cc1:Control'

Comment: Have you verified that you can register the tag fix in a page directive? If not, you may get a more informative error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To register server controls that are in the App_Code folder, you only need the tag prefix and namespace. So in web.config it would look like this...

```
<add tagPrefix="cc1" namespace="mynamespace"/>
```

And in a page it would look like this...

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" Namespace="mynamespace" %>
```

One gotcha to watch out for is that by default web site projects don't include any namespace at all when you add a new item to the App_Code folder, so you'll need to explicitly make sure your controls have a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to put the control into a DLL named "currentwebsitename.dll" (if you want it to work the second way) or you need to specify the source via the `src` attribute (if you want to do it the first way):

```
<add tagPrefix="cc1" namespace="mynamespace" src="app_code/control_name_here"/>
```

Try reading over these two articles as well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab.aspx and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f.aspx

Comment: The src attribute is only for user controls, which can't live in the App_Code folder. If you try to use anything in the App_Code folder in the src attribute you get the following error: The file '/Web/App_Code/CustomServerControl.cs' is in the special directory 'App_Code', which is not allowed.